# How can I manage multiples modules using IOC Containers

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I'm trying to create an application using multiples modules. I had an application with a single module but we just decide to split up.

We created two containers, the first one is moduleAContainer and the second one for moduleBContainer, I mean IOC contailers (Castle).

We have too an IoCWorker class that is responsible for keep an specific container static and provide some methods to resolve.

My problem is that, using ControllerFactory of Asp.net MVC for example, how can I decide with one should resolve my dependency?

Should be something like, IocWorker.Resolve("containername") but per web request? What is my parameter to decide it?

Can I do it using child containers?

Thank you so much.

Comment: What is this 'module' concept you are talking about and why do you use two seperate container instances?

Comment: Please make sure you understand the concept of the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Comment: I'm talking about two views of the same system. Each module is using the same database but, for example, I have these services ISaleAppService of Module A and ISaleAppService of Module B. I have one interface IUnitOfWork that is shared by theses two modules, but the problem is that my context that implements IUnityOfWork are diferent. So using only one container how can I do something like: Hey Ioc, if namespace is from moduleA resolve IUnityOfWork using concret instance of ModuleA context and if ModuleB do the same using concrete instance of ModuleB. but they are using the same IOC container.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to come up with a solution on your situation of two modules(Module A and B, by the way they both run same service interface ISaleAppService) having same interface (IUnitOfWork) with different implementation details solid classes.

So let's say it's a delivery app.

Module A uses Motorcycle to deliver 
DeliveryServiceA : IUnitOfWork { // deliver asap using motorcycle }

Module B uses Truck to deliver 
DeliverServiceB : IUnitOfWork { // deliver as loaded as possible using truck }

and the consumer, let's say ISaleAppService, buys the service and now, let's say it is not a concern of the consumer which service being used, Service(Module) A or B..

If that is the case, you need another service with implementation detail to make that decision for the user, mediator.. IMediator.

Consumer request => IMediator determines which service to use => choose between Service A or B (Module A or B).

If consumer needs to choose which service (which module), then probably you can provide key to distinguish such as input argument arg1.

Consumer request with key(arg1 or enum) via IUnitOfWork => IUnitOfWork determines which implementation block to choose (Module A or Module B) to send request, based on the key (or enum).

Whichever you design, I think there needs to be intermediate step no matter how you abstract using IUnitOfWork because there is implementation done differently behind the scene.